# Filter text file based on column value

Tags: if-statement, awk, conditional-statements

I have a text file with 26 columns and have to filter rows ONLY if column 22 has the value of '0', '1', '2' or '3' (out of 0-5).

If Column 22 has value '0','1', '2' or '3' (highlighted below), then remove anything less than 10 and greater 100 (based on column 5) AND remove anything less than 5.0 (this column has decimals) (based on column 13).

I am not sure how to insert the condition of do the following only if column 22 has the following values of 1 to 3 and retain the other rows (ie that has values 4 and 5)  as it is in the output file

```
awk -F "\t"  'NR==1; NR>1 {if ($5 > 10 && $5<100 && $13>5.0) print $0}' input.txt > output.txt
```

My input file is as follows

> Column1   ... Column5 ... Column13    ..  Column22
> ID1              a1           5                     0                                   5
> **ID2   a2          10                              1.2                                 0**
> **ID3   a3          4                               5.6                                 1**
> **ID4   a4          300                             2.6                                 2**
> **ID5   a5          40                              32                                  0**
> **ID6   a6          200                             4.6                                 3**
> ID7 a7          200                             4.5                                 5
> ID8 a8          3456                                4.9                                 4

and my desired output is

> Column1   Column5 Column13    Column22
>
> ID1   a1          5                               0                                   5
>
> ID5   a5          40                              32                                  0
>
> ID7   a7          200                             4.5                                 5
>
> ID8   a8          3456                                4.9                                 4

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: sample input and expected output would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry @piokuc, i have added the sample input and expected output now.

Comment: your sample input/output as is not usable since you omitted other columns where the script needs to refer for the right column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one alternative would be...

```
awk -F'\t' '{p=0<=$22 && $22<=3; q=10<$5 && $5<100 && 5<$13} NR==1 || q || !p ' file
```

You want the other conditions (q) applied only if `$22` is between 0 and 3 (p).

if you had a testable input output it could have been verified.

Comment: Thank you but this is giving a similar output as the code I tried as well, where it is filtering values 0-3 from $22 but not retaining the values 4 and 5 in the output.